# postgreSQL dump file generated when exporting is blank

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-dump, phppgadmin

I have a database named housing that I want to export. However, everytime i export it, it generates a blank dump file. I cannot identify what I've been doing wrong. Please help.

I'm trying using phppgadmin, I clicked export, selected SQL, structure  and data as format and then download, but the dump file generated is always blank.

I think I know now what the problem is, I have different two versions of postgreSQL installed on my laptop. postgreSQL version 9.3.6 that comes with Bitnami WAPPstack) and I forgot that I had previously installed postgreSQL version 9.4.1 too. I get a pg_dump aborting because of server version mismatch. How do I fix this? Can I just simply uninstall the one that is not with the Bitnami WAPPStack? Or will my database be deleted along with it? I'm sorry I know nothing . :(

Comment: Are you trying to export it via terminal or phppgadmin or pgadmin3. Also please share the code too.

Comment: I'm trying using phppgadmin, I clicked export, selected SQL, structure  and data as format and then download, but the dump file generated is always blank. @NandakumarV

Comment: From which page you have clicked the export link?  You should click export from the page with list all tables.

Comment: Dumping of complex table and schema names on Windows is not supported.     --This is now what the dump file is saying

Comment: Ahh... windows... I also had the same error long ago, but forgot how i solved it.. Can you check this page http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=faq#questions_on_dumps and see if anything works :)

Comment: I think I know now what the problem is, I have different two versions of postgreSQL installed on my laptop. postgreSQL version 9.3.6 that comes with Bitnami WAPPstack) and I forgot that I had previously installed postgreSQL version 9.4.1 too. I get a pg_dump aborting because of server version mismatch. How do I fix this? Can I just simply uninstall the one that is not with the Bitnami WAPPStack? Or will my database be deleted along with it? I'm sorry I know nothing . :( @NandakumarV

Answer (score 1):

http://www.expertphp.in/article/postgres-phppgadmin-problem-empty-sql-dump-after-export

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4W_6jnBXk0

Short:
In `/usr/share/phppgadmin/dbexport.php.`

Change the line from :
`$cmd = $exe . " -i";`
To
`$cmd = $exe;

and then change
`passthru($cmd);`
To
`echo passthru($cmd);`